# Convert bool to int in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run the following sql statement.

```
SELECT
item.item_number, SUM(item.item_active)
FROM 
public.item
GROUP BY item.item_number;
```

I am returning the following error:

```
ERROR:  function sum(boolean) does not exist
```

I figure if I can use a function to change the `item.item_active` to an integer, then it can take the sum of the active records.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try `boolean_col::int`:

```
SELECT
item.item_number, SUM(item.item_active::int)
FROM 
public.item
GROUP BY item.item_number;
```

Comment: thanks, I like this solution the most because it is the simplest.

Answer (score 5):

If that value you are getting is boolean then you can write case statement to count your active records.

```
SELECT
item.item_number, SUM(case when item.item_active then 1 else 0 end)
FROM 
public.item
GROUP BY item.item_number;
```